# Is it correct to say it like this?

Tags: grammar

- The girl, whom I love, passes from in front of my house daily.

Is this sentence grammatical? I want to say that a girl goes to her destination but she passes from in front of house on her way. How should I say it? I know something is wrong with the sentence.

Comment: You pass *from* a starting point, so *from* is very unlikely, unless she sleeps in front of your house every night.

Comment: hahhahh.... your sense of humour is extremely good.

Comment: The first part is ok, the second needs a little work.  *the girl, whom I love, passes in front of my house daily.* is probably the closest to your intended meaning.  But I'd recommend using a different verb.  *walks by my house every day* or *drives past my house* or *rides by my house* ...something like that.  You don't need the *whom* either:  *The girl I love, walks by my house every morning.*

Comment: Why can't I use from here? I want to know the reason.

Comment: When you use *pass from,* the *from* indicates the origin or starting point of the pass.  She can pass the house from the south, or she can pass from the left.  But if she passes from in front, where does she go and what does she pass?

Comment: "Every jest is an earnest in the womb of time" -Bernard Shaw

Comment: Can I say that: She walks by my home every day. What does "by" actually mean here? "by" means near to as told by Google.

Comment: It can also mean 'past'. See [Oxford Dictionaries Online](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/by?q=by), 5.1

Comment: So, does both these mean same. The shop is in front of my house. 2) The shop is by my house. Both are correct?

Comment: Both are correct but don't mean the same. The shop in front of your house is by (or near) your house but the shop by your house is not necessarily in front of your house, it can be next to, or round the corner, or at the back of your house...

Comment: In front is OK but opposite makes more sense in this case. Here's a good set of [illustrated vocabulary sheets](http://www.mes-english.com/flashcards/prepositions.php) to learn the prepositions.

Comment: hellodear: I think Stoney explained why you shouldn't use _from_ in his opening comment. Also, I would omit the commas, and the _whom_: **The girl I love passes in front of my house every day.** (Adding _whom_ isn't incorrect, but it isn't necessary, either.) As for "in front of" vs "by": A shop that's in front of my house is also by my house, but not every shop by my house is in front of my house (the shop could be beside my house, or in back of my house, and still be "by" my house). _By_ indicates proximity; _in front of_ indicates proximity and direction.

Answer (score 2):

The sentence is correct except for the commas and one or two words.

There should be no commas around the relative clause *whom I love* because this is a defining relative clause - it is necessary to the meaning of the sentence.

In English, you put commas around a relative clause if it adds additional information.  But this information doesn't change the meaning of the sentence.

My neighbor**, whose name is John,** is very friendly and helpful.

The relative clause in this sentence is a *non-defining relative clause*. It just tells us something more about the noun **neighbor**, but it isn't necessary to the meaning of what you want to say.  If you take the relative clause **whose name is John** out of the sentence, the sentence still says what you want to say.

My neighbor is very friendly and helpful.

Let's take your sentence:

The girl, whom I love, passes in front of my house daily.

If we take out the relative clause **whom I love** , the meaning of the sentence changes.

The girl passes in front of my house daily.

The relative clause **whom I love** is a *defining relative clause*.  That means, it defines the noun (the girl) very clearly.  She's the girl you love, not just some girl who walks by your house every day. So, don't put commas around that clause because it's important to the meaning of the sentence.

The girl who/whom I love passes by my house every day.

Comment: You'll find comma rules in English grammar books and online websites.  But not all native speakers agree with these rules.  Many rules were established a long time ago, so some people argue that they're outdated and that they even don't make any sense.  In German, for example, a defining relative clause **must** be set off with commas, while there should be **no** commas around it in English. This is hard for German learners of English to understand and then learn. But when you're teaching people who'll be translating, this difference is important for them to know.

Answer (score 0):

> The girl, whom I love, passes from in front of my house daily.

**"Whom I love"** can be useful for a particular effect.  You can shorten it for sure, but then it loses your formal voice.  Consider the following, inspired by "the girl whom I love":

> Each morning, **the girl whom I love** comes to me from the top of the eastern hill of my street.  Her golden red hair breaks the rising sun into yellow streaks of sideways sky.
>
> She walks not, but rather glides with grace while **passing in front of my house**. And she leaves me each day for the West where the buses meet familiar strangers on their way.
>
> And there, under the heat of the risen sun, diesel engines fire wheels forward to split the city apart.
>
> I see her beauty so clearly in one of those buses with tires rolling hot.  Her hair flows down like burning red rain, so close to my hand, in the seat in front of me, and she knows me not.